# Issue to hit webservice in sencha

Tags: web-services, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to call registration  webservive in sencha.When I call it on browser its seems ok.But i calling with in the app its gives following error.Please any body help me.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

here is my code

```
 Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'your custom loadmask'});
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: 'http://XXX.XXX.com/api/users/?',
        params: {

            first_name:'mohit',
            last_name:'bisht' ,
            city:'ramnagar',
            state:'UK',
            phone:'9073467465',
            email:'test@test.com',
            password_digest:'123456',
            op:'s'
        },
        success : function(response,opts) {
            Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);

            console.log(response.status);



        },
        failure : function(response,opts) {
            Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
            if (response.timedout) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'Request to server timed out.');
            }
            else if (response.aborted) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'Request Aborted by server.');
            }
            else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'Invalid Request to server.');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the service supports jsonp? you can try with an ajax request instead:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'your custom loadmask'});
Ext.Ajax.request({
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    cors: true,
    url: 'http://XXX.XXX.com/api/users/?',

    params: {
        first_name:'mohit',
        last_name:'bisht' ,
        city:'ramnagar',
        state:'UK',
        phone:'9073467465',
        email:'test@test.com',
        password_digest:'123456',
        op:'s'
    },

    success : function(response,opts) {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
        console.log(response.status);
    },

    failure : function(response,opts) {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
        if (response.timedout) Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'Request to server timed out.');
        else if (response.aborted) Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'Request Aborted by server.');
        else Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'Invalid Request to server.');
    }
});
```

Hope it helps-